# existing state of package has been invalidated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing this error.

I have two Schema Schema A and Schema B

Schema B contains a table my_table in which values are being Inserted.

There is also a triggger my_trigger written for my_table in schemaB for each row

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schemaB.my_trigger
               ON schemaA.my_table
               FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
               IF INSERTING THEN
                  schemaA.my_package.my_procedure (:NEW.field_A,NEW.field_B, :NEW.field_C);
               END IF;
            EXCEPTION
               WHEN OTHERS THEN
                Insert into my_log(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,sysdate);
            END my_trigger;
            /    AFTER INSERT
```

This trigger written on my_table of schemaB is calling a procedure which is present in Schema A.

However when the trigger is being fired I am getting the below error in my logs

```
            ERROR: ORA-04061: existing state of package "schemaA.my_package" has been invalidated
            ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "schemaA.my_package"
            ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "schemaA.my_package"
            ORA-06512: at "schemaB.my_trigger", line 17      10/1/2015 6:38:07 PM
```

Also the procedure in schemaA is declared as PRAGMA_AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION

Is this some grants issue as i checked all the grants has been given, I have checked dependencies of the both trigger and procedure
and all seems to valid. Can you kindly help?

I have tried using Pragma serially_reusable in the calling package but still giving me same error

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646123/ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded-ora-04065-not-execute)

Comment: tried  by making the calling package as  serially_reusable but still the same error..

Comment: Could you attach `schemaA.my_package` ddl please?

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues you can have is:

- The package/procedure you are calling is invalid
  check this query whether you have an entry of your package or objects used in your package in this all_objects view

  select * from all_objects where status = 'INVALID' and owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';
- Check your package is having global variables? if yes then check if those variable is not being changed by any other session
- run below script to compile all the objects in your schema

  begin
     dbms_utility.compile_schema('SCHEMA_NAME',false); 
     end;
- Last option if none of the above works then remove all the procedures/function from your package, add new function and try to run your function from the trigger. check if this works then your package is in special lock. after adding a new function it's state will be valid again and then you can add all your actual funcs/procs and remove the newly added one.