# Oracle job failed. How do I implement a 30 minute wait and then retry the job?

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs

job has run fine for months and then this morning I get this:

ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure

Regardless of the error, how would I implement a WAIT then RETRY for my job? I can't seem to find the WAIT piece in the documentation but surely this has to be there right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646123/ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded-ora-04065-not-execute)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That's just the error I received. I want to know how to put a WAIT and RETRY in the oracle job scheduler.

Comment: Retry to reset the timing of your job without touching any settings, it will run. Since, it seems some sub-procedures of your main package are compiled and needed to be compiled for only once for whole main package which's called by your job. That's just a classical reaction of Oracle DB.